# Кол-во записей в одной таблице, если записи совпадают с другой таблицей

Tags: sql

Есть таблица

```
 books
    id name    date_created
    1   book1  1469527903
    2   book2  1469527903
    3   book3  1469527903
```

Есть таблица

```
 sold_books 
    book_id book_price
    1       10
    1       20
    2       30
    2       21
```

Вот какая задача:
Вывести кол-во из books, если только book_id в sold_books совпадает с book.id, и book.date_created = '1469527903';
В общем должно получится: 2
Так как книги с айди: 1, 2 проданы.

Пробую такой запрос

```
SELECT 
count(books.id) count_sold_books
FROM 
    `books` as books
INNER JOIN
    `sold_books`
    ON
        books.id = sold_books.book_id;
```

И мне выводит **4** записи, то е сть из sold_books.

Пробовал и LEFT JOIN, и RIGHT JOIN...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего так:

```
SELECT 
count(DISTINCT books.id) count_sold_books
FROM 
    `books` as books
INNER JOIN
    `sold_books`
    ON
        books.id = sold_books.book_id;
```

Но сработает не везде (в Access'e например не сработает), тогда можно можно просто обернуть в еще один запрос.

```
SELECT COUNT(b.id) AS count_sold_books
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT books.id
    FROM `books` as books
    INNER JOIN `sold_books` ON books.id = sold_books.book_id;
    ) AS b
```

[Смотри здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)

Comment: А если мне нужно еще добавить условие, WHERE b.date_created = '1469527903', как дописать? Я дописываю после 'AS b', а мне пишет что такой колонки нет, хотя она есть то.. Сложный запрос для меня

Comment: Все, получилось, нужно было условие добавять перед закрытием скобок.